# How to stub a ruby method and conditionally raise an exception based upon state of object

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, rspec2

In short, I want to raise an exception via a stubbed method, but only if the object that has the stubbed method has a particular state.

```
Mail::Message.any_instance.stub(:deliver) do
  if to == "notarealemailaddress!@#!@#"
    raise Exception, "SMTP Error"
  else
    return true
  end
end
```

This doesn't work, because the context inside the stub block is: RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2::Nested_2.

**How do I get access to the stubbed object?**

using ruby 2, rspec 2.

The actual scenario is I have an app that sounds out thousands of emails in batches and I have code that catches SMTP exceptions, logs the batch, and proceeds.  So I want to test sending several batches, where one of the batches in the middle throws an exception.

Comment: It's best not to use conditionals in your tests at all. Why not create two tests, one positive and one negative?

Comment: Because I'm testing exception handling while iterating over an array, essentially.  So I want one object in the array to throw an exception when a method on it is called; so I need to stub a method but only on a particular object that I don't have access to in the test itself because the method I'm testing creates the objects internally.  Perhaps thats indicative of a smell, but I'm writing tests for someone else's code and I don't want to change too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's how you can get this behavior fairly easily without upgrading:

```
class Rspec::Mocks::MessageExpectation
  # pulling in behavior from rspec v3 that I really really really need, ok?
  # when upgrading to v3, delete me!
  def invoke_with_orig_object(parent_stub, *args, &block)
    raise "Delete me.  I was just stubbed to pull in behavior from RSpec v3 before it was production ready to fix a bug!  But now I see you are using Rspec v3. See this commit: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/commit/ebd1cdae3eed620bd9d9ab08282581ebc2248535#diff-060466b2a68739ac2a2798a9b2e78643" if RSpec::Version::STRING > "2.99.0.pre"
    args.unshift(@method_double.object)
    invoke_without_orig_object(parent_stub, *args, &block)
  end
  alias_method_chain :invoke, :orig_object
end
```

Drop that at the bottom of your spec file.  You'll notice I even add a check to raise an error once RSpec is upgraded.  boom!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is solved in the latest(currently alpha) version of Rspec v3:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/commit/ebd1cdae3eed620bd9d9ab08282581ebc2248535#diff-060466b2a68739ac2a2798a9b2e78643

```
it "passes the instance as the first arg of the implementation block" do
   instance = klass.new

   expect { |b|
     klass.any_instance.should_receive(:bees).with(:sup, &b)
     instance.bees(:sup)
   }.to yield_with_args(instance, :sup)
end
```

Comment: +1 Nice find and fascinating test. I'm amazed at some of the ways RSpec uses itself to validate itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you specify the arguments using the `with` method, so in your case it would be something along the lines of:

```
Mail::Message.any_instance.stub(:deliver).with(to: "notarealemailaddress!@#!@#") do
    raise Exception, "SMTP Error"
end
```

There's full documentation here:
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-3/docs/method-stubs

Comment: I don't think this works.  When you specify #with, I don't think the block is executued.